# How to represent the same appointment for different weeks on calendar?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I've been working on my own specific calendar library on tailwind-css and react, representing different events for particular range of the dates. I need to implement feature with events which stretch across date cells based on startDay, endDay with (i guess) absolute positioning.
I would like to have something like [this](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/scheduler/demos/featured/overview/) library has.
Here is what i mean(look at the arrows):
[image]

I tried my best in different ways, for now i have all events repeating in every dayCell so it looks like i have a long event stretching for many cells, but there is a bug when one of the events ends or a new one appears it doesn't look as supposed to be.

Example:
[image]

How could I show the same event in different lines? Maybe someone could give an idea to think or solution, I've tried to google something like that, but couldn't find anything. I think this could be also useful for those who wants to create their own calendar with events, stretching and drag'n'drop.

**UPDATE**:

I need to implement multiline tasks for the calendar, but I have no idea how to do such a functional. For example data for the coming event can be: `const data = [{title: "Task 1", startDay: new Date("2022/12/10"), endDay: new Date("2023/01/10"), color: "red"}]`
[image]

Comment: Hi, could you provide a Minimal Reproducible Example? Show us some code of the specific problem.

Comment: @Chiel check out this link: https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/scheduler/docs/guides/appointments/#recurring-appointments there is "Recurring-appointments" section, switch to the "Month view" and you will see the logic I want to do in my project.

Comment: @DmitryBochok Please share some code or create a CodeSandbox.

Comment: Could you possibly share a sandbox code, so that we could tweak it to your requirements.

Comment: @Chiel I setup codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/small-hill-xeobwc?file=/src/CycleCell.jsx

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use a `relative grid` and place the event `absolute` to the `relative grid`.

**Code Structure**

```
<div class="p-8">
  
  <div class="relative grid grid-cols-7 grid-rows-5 ...">        relative grid

    <div class="bg-white"></div>
                                                                 Place all your grids here 
    <div class="bg-white"></div>
    
    <div class="absolute inset-0 grid grid-cols-7 grid-rows-5">  absolute grid for events
      <div class="col-start-3 col-end-8 row-start-3 flex items-end">
        <div> This is your event </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-start-1 col-end-3 row-start-4 flex items-end ">
        <div> Which spans till here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Link:** [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/5lrQS9C1jf)

Comment: I was thinking about this solution, but how will you assign exact task to exact сells if there is an array of cell's ids, like startDayId, endDayId? Set col-start-[dayId] row-start-[weekid]? Presume that we could adjust backend data the way we want

Comment: Also, what if I want to add more events, will they position one under another?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using grid - no absolute positioning required. In fact absolute is definetely not a good solution as absolutely positioned element have no space and multiple events will stack on each other or stretched on a next week

Take a look at [this calendar](https://play.tailwindcss.com/7BFgDQmjDR) based on CSS Grid only

There are few concepts

- **Each week has 2 grid rows** (total 10 grid rows = 5weeks * 2rows) - one untouched for dates, and second one - for events. Date row has height of 3rem as defined in `grid-rows-[repeat(10,minmax(3rem,min-content))]`, event row - min-content height. This mean we have grid 7 on 10 (at least 6 rem height if there are no events at all)
- Each day of week should start from appropriate column as a day (`col-start-1` for Sunday, `col-start-2` for Monday, etc) and even calendar row (`row-start-1` - week 1, `row-start-3` - week 2, etc). If you wish to create such class dynamically consider to [safelist](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) all possible values
- Event wrapper is a grid itself with the same amount of columns as calendar (7) and as many rows as you need. Every event wrapper starts on row of calendar grid multiplied by 2 (week 1 - start row 2 `row-start-2`, week 2 - `row-start-4`, etc)
- Each event within wrapper should start from some day `col-start-<start-day-of-week>` (eg, `col-start-1` - starts from Sunday) and ends on another day `col-end-<end-day-of-week>` - therefore it should be easy to stretch event on a few days within code (make sure event object returns start and end day position from 1 to 8. 8 in case if start day is 7 - Saturday)

Extra:

- Each event within wrapper has `self-end` utility to be placed at the bottom of the wrapper
- You may use [line-clamp](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-line-clamp) plugin to prevent huge event description

Comment: For example if you have a range of dates  for the event from backend starting from Day 3, Week 2- Day 5, Week 3 how would you create single task on 2 weeks with given solution?

Comment: @DmitryBochok check the event and separate it on tow or more depends on start/end date when mapping events or something

Answer (score 0):

I think the following approach is fine and could be potentially more robust, since events for each cell is individually calculated and stored:

> have all events repeating in every dayCell so it looks like i have a long event stretching for many cells

The placement logic of events for a cell need to:

1. Define a number of slots for the cell which can contain events, or other items for display.
2. Check previous cell for any ongoing events being carried over, and allocate the matching place for them, so that the display is consistent across cells and visually connected.
3. Check if there are events starting on the date of current cell, and place the new events to any unoccupied slots.
4. Assign a marker for each cell, so that the render component can display a few variants of events based on conditions, such as `start`, `middle`, and `end` status.

The posted sandbox seems to be missing some configurations, so I copied the code to a new one, and tried to add some rough logic for events placement.

It is far from optimized, but here is a demo on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-y3km78?file=src/App.jsx).

This example defines each cell with 5 slots for events (the number customizable from props), and generates a `taskSlotsByDate` from given range of dates.

As a recipe for output, `taskSlotsByDate` organizes events into available slots for each day, following the above list of logic.

```
// Add dates in range for tasks for easier search
const tasksWithDates = props.tasks.map((item) => {
  const start = new Date(new Date(item.startDate).setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
  const end = new Date(new Date(item.endDate).setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
  const dates = getDatesInRange(start, end);
  return { ...item, dates };
});

// Assign tasks to available slots by date
const taskSlotsByDate = [];
cycleDates.forEach((date, index) => {
  // Define empty slots for default
  const currentSlots = Array(props.slots || 5).fill({ type: "empty" });
  // Get relevant tasks
  const relevantTasks = tasksWithDates.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const currentDay = cur.dates.findIndex(
      (item) => item.getTime() === date.getTime()
    );

    // When task is not relevant for this date
    if (currentDay === -1) return acc;
    const totalDays = cur.dates.length;
    const { title, color, status } = cur;
    let variant = "middle-day";
    if (totalDays === 1 && currentDay === 0) variant = "single-day";
    if (totalDays > 1 && currentDay === 0) variant = "start-day";
    if (totalDays > 1 && currentDay === totalDays - 1) variant = "end-day";
    // Title is used as id here but preferably add an id property to task data
    return [...acc, { variant, title, color, status, id: cur?.id || title }];
  }, []);

  // When none of tasks is relevant for the date
  if (relevantTasks.length === 0) {
    taskSlotsByDate[index] = [...currentSlots];
    return;
  }

  // When this is first date in range
  if (index === 0) {
    const newSlots = currentSlots.map((slot, index) => {
      if (!relevantTasks[index]) return slot;
      return { type: "task", task: { ...relevantTasks[index] } };
    });
    taskSlotsByDate[index] = newSlots;
    return;
  }

  const ongoingTasks = relevantTasks.filter(
    (task) => task.variant === "middle-day" || task.variant === "end-day"
  );

  const newTasks = relevantTasks.filter(
    (task) => task.variant === "start-day" || task.variant === "single-day"
  );

  // Assign carry over tasks to slots at previous index
  ongoingTasks.forEach((task) => {
    if (!taskSlotsByDate[index - 1]) return;
    const prevTaskIndex = taskSlotsByDate[index - 1].findIndex((prev) => {
      const { task: prevTask } = prev;
      if (!prevTask) return false;
      return prevTask.id === task.id;
    });
    if (prevTaskIndex === -1) return;
    currentSlots[prevTaskIndex] = { type: "task", task };
  });

  // Assgin new tasks to slots only in unoccupied slot
  let newTaskIndex = 0;
  const newSlots = currentSlots.map((slot) => {
    if (slot.type === "task" || !newTasks[newTaskIndex]) return slot;
    const updatedSlot = { type: "task", task: { ...newTasks[newTaskIndex] } };
    newTaskIndex += 1;
    return updatedSlot;
  });
  taskSlotsByDate[index] = newSlots;
  return;
});
```

Iteration of `taskSlotsByDate` can be included in the output of `cycleDates`, and renders a custom component `Task` for each slot:

```
{
  cycleDates.map((day, index) => (
    <div
      key={day.toString()}
      className={cn(
        "min-w-36 min-h-[176px] border-r border-b border-354548",
        props.className
      )}
    >
      <p className="py-4">{props.id}</p>
      <div className="grid grid-flow-row gap-y-2">
        <div className="text-xs truncate">{day.toDateString()}</div>
        {taskSlotsByDate[index].map((item, index) => {
          return <Task key={index} type={item.type} {...item["task"]} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  ));
}
```

`Task` renders the right variant of event based on conditions:

```
const Task = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="relative w-full h-6 text-sm text-white">
      {props.type === "empty" ? (
        <figure className="bg-white-500 h-6"></figure>
      ) : (
        <figure
          className={cn(
            "absolute w-full overflow-hidden",
            {
              "bg-red-500": props.color === "red",
              "bg-violet-500": props.color === "violet",
              "bg-orange-500": props.color === "orange",
              "bg-green-500": props.color === "green",
              "bg-blue-500": props.color === "blue",
              "bg-purple-500": props.color === "purple",
            },
            {
              "inset-y-0 right-0 rounded-l-full": props.variant === "start-day",
              "inset-y-0 left-0 rounded-r-full": props.variant === "end-day",
              "inset-y-0 rounded-full": props.variant === "single-day",
              "inset-0": props.variant === "middle-day",
            }
          )}
        >
          {props.variant === "start-day"
            ? "start"
            : props.variant === "end-day"
            ? "end"
            : props.variant === "single-day"
            ? "single"
            : "middle"}
        </figure>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```